# armadillo cov function doesn't work

Tags: armadillo

I am not sure what is the problem, I have a matrix define as:

```
int N  = 52;
mat y(N, 2);

//  some operation
y(0, 0) = ...;
y(0, 1) = ...;
y(1, 0) = ...;
......
y(51, 1) = ...;

cout << cov(y) << endl;
```

The operations are very basic ones and I can print `y`, Then I get the result

```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 7 was incorrect on entry to DSYRK .
  -5.5368  -0.2230
  -0.2230  -0.0090
```

There is negative elements on the diagonal.

With the same data, I copy the `y` I printed to MATLAB and use matlab `cov` function and I get the result

```
 0.0232   -0.0062
-0.0062    0.0078
```

Have no idea what happened behind the `cov` function in armadillo.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You should provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).